# pexpect - telnet not waiting for output so child.before is empty

Tags: python, expect, cisco, pexpect, command-line-interface

Greetz,

I have searched for quite some time on this topic so I am hoping to get some input here.
I understand that I can have a timeout defined but I don't think that is whats required in this case.

Basically, the string that I am populating is returning empty.
In this scenario, I am connecting to a networking device via telnet and issing a commmand.
If I log the session and check the log, I see the command issued but we don't wait for a response.

```
child.expect('%s' % prompt);
child.sendline('\r');

child.expect('%s' % prompt);


time.sleep(3)
child.sendline('version \r');
child.expect('%s' % prompt)
version =  child.before


print version
```

Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: If you try without the `\r`, does it work? That shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Looks like it was how the console server was resturning / buffering in some way. This works fine on other systems. Thanks anyway.